# Exposing REST API only for a short period of time

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-session

I am working on a project which is already using `spring-security` `Jwt` for `authentication` of every incoming request. I need to add another REST controller in the same module with different path like `/api/v1/statement`. All api's inside this controller should be accesible to the user only for 30 mins(same user) with some temporary toekn. Post 30 mins that token should expire and API should be no longer accesible to the user. Can anybody here please suggest how can i achieve this using spring security?

I checked few blogs related to the spring security but couldn't find what i am looking for.

Comment: You could create a new custom token that has an expiration field and then implement a custom AuthenticationProvider and Filter for only this /api/v1/statement path only and verify the token there. I don't know how your current SecurityConfig is done..

Comment: Thanks @lapadets. I was able find a work around. Thanks for your suggestion though.